# Change TextView from another activity

Tags: android

What i need is what i write at EditText campoempresa and camporesponsavel, i need to show at DiagnosticoActivity, but the program show null or nothing. I'm using a Firebase Database, have another way to do that?

The FirstActivity

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String textoequipe = campoequipe.getText().toString();
            String textoempresa = campoempresa.getText().toString();
            String textosetor = camposetor.getText().toString();
            String textoresponsavel = camporesponsavel.getText().toString();



            Intent myintent = new Intent(NovoActivity.this, DiagnosticoActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            Bundle.getString("campoempresa", textoempresa);
            Bundle.getString("camporesponsavel", textoresponsavel);
            startActivity(myintent);



            if ( !textoequipe.isEmpty()){
                if ( !textoempresa.isEmpty()){
                    if ( !textosetor.isEmpty()){
                        if ( !textoresponsavel.isEmpty()){

                            informações = new Informações();
                            informações.setEquipe( textoequipe );
                            informações.setEmpresa( textoempresa );
                            informações.setSetor( textosetor );
                            informações.setResponsavel( textoresponsavel );

                            informações.salvar();
```

The SecondActivity

```
public class DiagnosticoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btbloco;
private Button btanotacoes;
private Button btfotos;
private ImageButton btvnovo;
private ImageButton btvfinalizar;
private TextView EmpresaResponsavel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnostico);




    EmpresaResponsavel = findViewById(R.id.EmpresaResponsavel);

    Intent myintent = getIntent();
    String textoempresa = myintent.getStringExtra("campoempresa");
    String textoresponsavel = myintent.getStringExtra("camporesponsavel");
    EmpresaResponsavel.setText(textoempresa + " - " + textoresponsavel);
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: you can use a broadcast intent/intent to pass arguments between activities, alternately you can create an interface, or lately you can use livedata and livedata observer classes

Comment: you seem to be using the wrong intent when retrieving your data...  try using getIntent().getString("blah")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 problems that i can see...

in the first activity use Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtra("bundle") to retrieve the bundle and then bundle.getString("campoempresa") to get the value of the string...

in the second activity you are not attaching the bundle to the intent...

use myIntent.putExtra(bundle)

create the bundle and start activity:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DiagnosticsoActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("campoempresa", textoempresa);
    bundle.putString("camporesponsave1", textoresponsave1);
    myIntent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

retrieve the bundle in the activity:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtra("bundle");
    String textoempresa = bundle.getString("campoempresa");
    String textoresponsave1 = bundle.getString("camporesponsave1")
```

Comment: Although, I wouldn't create a bundle in the first place, I would just add extras to the intent...

Comment: error: non-static method putString(String,String) cannot be referenced from a static context Bundle.putString("campoempresa", textoempresa);

Comment: this is the correct method.  besides Bundle.putString("campoempresa", textoempresa) --> bundle.putString("campoempresa", textoempresa);

Comment: thanks, but now another error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.pichau.diagnstico.DiagnosticoActivity.onCreate

Answer (score 1):

start activity:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class).putExtra("campoempresa", textoempresa).putExtra("camporesponsave1", textoresponsave1));
```

Retrieve value:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
 String v1 = i.getStringExtra("campoempresa");
 String v2 = i.getStringExtra("camporesponsave1");
```

Comment: with this show null at the EmpresaResponsavel.setText